# HTML elements left to right with no gap in 2 columns

Tags: jquery, html, css, angular, masonry

I'M working on a page where I'll show news in 2 columns. The elements width will be the same, it should be responsive -goes to 1 column if the viewport is smaller, but I've already know how to do it-.
& it is an angular2 project.

The problem comes here, when the element's height is not equal I need something like this:

```
|AAA|BBB|
|AAA|BBB|
|AAA|CCC|
|DDD|CCC|
|DDD|EEE|
......
```

So basically I need something when instead of keep the lines the html fill the gaps.
I've already found Masonry, which could be a great solution but unfortunately I can't use it because I work with Angular2 and the ported angular2-masonry project is dead... with a lot of issues and I can't fix them unfortunately..
Other jquery libraries based on the previous one is not an option.. without a ported version to angular2 they are barely usable. (if you know something which should work I will try it!)
The other option is the *magic css*. I've found alternatives but almost all of them sort the elements top to bottom, which is not good for me. The only one I've found after a lot research is this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/veGmgJ but unfortunately I don't know how should I use it in my solution...
my solution basically is not a big deal: I've a div (or whatever you want) with an ngFor..

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox might be what you're after and it can handle the stacking columns as well. Heres an example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aLmzVa

```
.flexContainer {
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flexItem {
  flex: 1 0 250px;
  border: 1px solid;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as I see the smaller elements get the height of the heightes in the actual row which is quite not the behaviour I'm looking for :(